# How to extract the following data?

Tags: list-manipulation, data, filtering

Consider the following table:

```
E 0 -1 -1.0000000000000000e+00 -1.0000000000000000e+00 -1.0000000000000000e+00 0 0 13 1 2 0 2 1.0000000000000000e+00 5.8956999999999993e-01
P 17 22 -1.2485021051898233e-02 -5.1630826532250172e-02 6.1918258041651630e-05 5.3118940435030619e-02 0 1 0 0 0 0
P 18 22 4.9562715584439615e-02 5.0012892263022642e-02 8.6245790603881711e-02 1.1133772301203836e-01 0 1 0 0 0 0
P 19 22 -1.5552509953220044e-02 -2.3850666659370811e-02 6.5939681353609694e-03 2.9226961554557555e-02 0 1 0 0 0 0
P 20 22 2.7596054487740468e-01 -2.1762061713315523e-01 8.7662314134485303e-02 3.6221214315627603e-01 0 1 0 0 0 0
P 21 22 -5.1578463837396671e-02 1.3519803581552983e-02 -1.9108577184834183e-01 1.9838572333609578e-01 0 1 0 0 0 0
P 22 22 1.2113834175920507e-01 -3.2018418728691583e-01 2.7446441033903723e-01 4.3877457102196354e-01 0 1 0 0 0 0
E 1 -1 -1.0000000000000000e+00 -1.0000000000000000e+00 -1.0000000000000000e+00 0 0 6 1 2 0 2 1.0000000000000000e+00 5.8956999999999993e-01
P 7 130 -1.8129648644252511e-02 5.2696520170431738e-01 7.5951516109473693e-01 1.0500000000000000e+00 4.9761000000000000e-01 1 0 0 0 0
P 8 211 1.6865230841167808e-01 -4.0708930815825645e-01 -6.2344440715555249e-01 7.7609794463256632e-01 1.3957000000000000e-01 1 0 0 0 0
P 9 -211 -1.5052265976742557e-01 -1.1987589354606093e-01 -1.3607075393918455e-01 2.7390205536743384e-01 1.3957000000000000e-01 1 0 0 0 0
E 2 -1 -1.0000000000000000e+00 -1.0000000000000000e+00 -1.0000000000000000e+00 0 0 5 1 2 0 2 1.0000000000000000e+00 5.8956999999999993e-01
P 7 211 5.0607845359036219e-01 3.6848311348479607e-01 8.3133928632546694e-01 1.0499999999999987e+00 1.3957000000000000e-01 1 0 0 0 0
P 8 -211 -5.0607845359036241e-01 -3.6848311348479629e-01 -8.3133928632546772e-01 1.0500000000000000e+00 1.3957000000000000e-01 1 0 0 0 0
E 3 -1 -1.0000000000000000e+00 -1.0000000000000000e+00 -1.0000000000000000e+00 0 0 12 1 2 0 2 1.0000000000000000e+00 5.8956999999999993e-01
P 11 211 -1.2670630161528043e-01 -5.5755103314066323e-01 -2.0333395392349726e-02 5.8890650641118336e-01 1.3957000000000000e-01 1 0 0 0 0
P 13 -211 -1.8625168359526698e-01 2.5964633799700204e-01 -1.4171605493559536e-01 3.7638960613151057e-01 1.3957000000000000e-01 1 0 0 0 0
P 15 211 1.4689307696016242e-02 2.6397035763873505e-01 1.7916303460509408e-01 3.4853307352590812e-01 1.3957000000000000e-01 1 0 0 0 0
P 16 -211 1.1984605870831583e-01 6.2191999311472013e-02 5.2260939697877366e-02 2.0110174858608362e-01 1.3957000000000000e-01 1 0 0 0 0
```

It has the structure

```
E ...
P ...
P ...
...
E ...
P ...
...
```

Let us call the corresponding table "table.txt":

```
data = Import["table.txt","Table"];
```

I would like to make a command `extract[data,i]` that extracts the rows with `P ...` after the given `E ...` defined by the index `i` (given by its order, say, the first `E ...` is 1, and so on) and before the subsequent `E ...` having the index `i+1`. Could you please tell me how to do it?

Comment: You could start by using Position on the first column to find where all the E’s are.

Comment: You may be able to use [SplitByPatterns](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/SplitByPatterns/) in the Wolfram function repository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using your imported `data`, first we find the rows with "E" in the first column, and from that list, we make a list of ranges.

```
ranges = Partition[Flatten[Position[data[[All, 1]], "E"]], 2, 1, 1] - Threaded[{0, 1}];
ranges[[-1, 2]] = Length[data]; (*set the end of the last range*)
ranges
(*{{1, 7}, {8, 11}, {12, 14}, {15, 19}}*)
```

The command `extract[data, i]` is the same as selecting a range. For example, to extract the first set of rows from `data` use:

```
data[[#1 ;; #2]] &@@ ranges[[1]]
```

> ```
> {{E,0,-1,-1.,-1.,-1.,0,0,13,1,2,0,2,1.,0.58957},
>  {P,17,22,-0.012485,-0.0516308,0.0000619183,0.0531189,0,1,0,0,0,0},
>  {P,18,22,0.0495627,0.0500129,0.0862459,0.111338,0,1,0,0,0,0},
>  {P,19,22,-0.0155525,-0.0238507,0.00659397,0.029227,0,1,0,0,0,0},
>  {P,20,22,0.275961,-0.217621,0.0876623,0.362212,0,1,0,0,0,0},
>  {P,21,22,-0.0515785,0.0135198,-0.191086,0.198386,0,1,0,0,0,0},
>  {P,22,22,0.121138,-0.320184,0.274464,0.438775,0,1,0,0,0,0}}
> ```

Then the second set of rows is `data[[#1 ;; #2]] &@@ ranges[[2]]`, etc.

Comment: Thanks! It's super-fast.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the format will be the same as the example posted:

```
data = "E0-1-1.0000000000000000e+00-1.0000000000000000e+00-1.\
0000000000000000e+00 0 0 13 1 2 0 2 1.0000000000000000e+00 \
5.8956999999999993e-01
P 17 22-1.2485021051898233e-02-5.1630826532250172e-02 \
6.1918258041651630e-05 5.3118940435030619e-02 0 1 0 0 0 0
P 18 22 4.9562715584439615e-02 5.0012892263022642e-02 \
8.6245790603881711e-02 1.1133772301203836e-01 0 1 0 0 0 0
P 19 22-1.5552509953220044e-02-2.3850666659370811e-02 \
6.5939681353609694e-03 2.9226961554557555e-02 0 1 0 0 0 0
P 20 22 2.7596054487740468e-01-2.1762061713315523e-01 \
8.7662314134485303e-02 3.6221214315627603e-01 0 1 0 0 0 0
P 21 22-5.1578463837396671e-02 \
1.3519803581552983e-02-1.9108577184834183e-01 1.9838572333609578e-01 \
0 1 0 0 0 0
P 22 22 1.2113834175920507e-01-3.2018418728691583e-01 \
2.7446441033903723e-01 4.3877457102196354e-01 0 1 0 0 0 0
E 1-1-1.0000000000000000e+00-1.0000000000000000e+00-1.\
0000000000000000e+00 0 0 6 1 2 0 2 1.0000000000000000e+00 \
5.8956999999999993e-01
P 7 130-1.8129648644252511e-02 5.2696520170431738e-01 \
7.5951516109473693e-01 1.0500000000000000e+00 4.9761000000000000e-01 \
1 0 0 0 0
P 8 211 1.6865230841167808e-01-4.0708930815825645e-01-6.\
2344440715555249e-01 7.7609794463256632e-01 1.3957000000000000e-01 1 \
0 0 0 0
P 9-211-1.5052265976742557e-01-1.1987589354606093e-01-1.\
3607075393918455e-01 2.7390205536743384e-01 1.3957000000000000e-01 1 \
0 0 0 0
E 2-1-1.0000000000000000e+00-1.0000000000000000e+00-1.\
0000000000000000e+00 0 0 5 1 2 0 2 1.0000000000000000e+00 \
5.8956999999999993e-01
P 7 211 5.0607845359036219e-01 3.6848311348479607e-01 \
8.3133928632546694e-01 1.0499999999999987e+00 1.3957000000000000e-01 \
1 0 0 0 0
P 8-211-5.0607845359036241e-01-3.6848311348479629e-01-8.\
3133928632546772e-01 1.0500000000000000e+00 1.3957000000000000e-01 1 \
0 0 0 0
E 3-1-1.0000000000000000e+00-1.0000000000000000e+00-1.\
0000000000000000e+00 0 0 12 1 2 0 2 1.0000000000000000e+00 \
5.8956999999999993e-01
P 11 211-1.2670630161528043e-01-5.5755103314066323e-01-2.\
0333395392349726e-02 5.8890650641118336e-01 1.3957000000000000e-01 1 \
0 0 0 0
P 13-211-1.8625168359526698e-01 \
2.5964633799700204e-01-1.4171605493559536e-01 3.7638960613151057e-01 \
1.3957000000000000e-01 1 0 0 0 0
P 15 211 1.4689307696016242e-02 2.6397035763873505e-01 \
1.7916303460509408e-01 3.4853307352590812e-01 1.3957000000000000e-01 \
1 0 0 0 0
P 16-211 1.1984605870831583e-01 6.2191999311472013e-02 \
5.2260939697877366e-02 2.0110174858608362e-01 1.3957000000000000e-01 \
1 0 0 0 0";
```

split the data each time there's a newline command. Get the first character in each line, and determine where the "E"s are

```
splitData = StringSplit[data, "\n"];
letters = StringPart[splitData, 1]
ePos = Flatten[Position[letters, "E"]]

(*{"E", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "E", "P", "P", "P", "E", "P", \
"P", "E", "P", "P", "P", "P"}*)
(*{1, 8, 12, 15}*)
```

Then make the upper and lower index bounds for the "P" lines between "E" lines (there is probably a lot simpler way to do this):

```
eBounds = MapThread[{#1+1, #2 - 1} &, {ePos, ePos // RotateLeft}];
eBounds[[-1]] = {Last@ePos+1, Length@letters};
eBounds
(*{{2, 7}, {9, 11}, {13, 14}, {16, 19}}*)
```

And grab those parts from `data`:

```
groupedData = 
  Map[Part[splitData, #] &, Range[First[#], Last[#]]] & /@ eBounds;
```

To make it a function, we just first create our grouped data with another function first (using the same code as above):

```
createGroupedData[dataIn_] := Module[{data = dataIn},
  splitData = StringSplit[data, "\n"];
  letters = StringPart[splitData, 1];
  ePos = Flatten[Position[letters, "E"]];
  eBounds = 
   MapThread[{#1 + 1, #2 - 1} &, {ePos, ePos // RotateLeft}];
  eBounds[[-1]] = {Last@ePos + 1, Length@letters};
  
  Map[Part[splitData, #] &, Range[First[#], Last[#]]] & /@ eBounds
  
  ]
```

And then you can just get the `i`th part of the output from createGroupData:

```
groupedPs = createGroupedData[data];
groupedPs[[2]]

(*{"P 7 130-1.8129648644252511e-02 5.2696520170431738e-01 \
7.5951516109473693e-01 1.0500000000000000e+00 4.9761000000000000e-01 \
1 0 0 0 0", "P 8 211 \
1.6865230841167808e-01-4.0708930815825645e-01-6.2344440715555249e-01 \
7.7609794463256632e-01 1.3957000000000000e-01 1 0 0 0 0", "P \
9-211-1.5052265976742557e-01-1.1987589354606093e-01-1.\
3607075393918455e-01 2.7390205536743384e-01 1.3957000000000000e-01 1 \
0 0 0 0"}*)
```

Comment: I suggest that `eBounds[[-1]] = {Last@ePos, Length@letters}` should be `eBounds[[-1]] = {Last@ePos+1, Length@letters}` so that `eBounds[[-1]]` starts at the first 'P' (`Last@ePos + 1`) row after the last 'E' row (`Last@ePos`).

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out I have fixed it

Answer (score 4):

Working with the `file` from your previous [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/289114/how-to-extract-the-following-data-from-the-file):

```
file = Import["C:/tag_1_pythia8_events.hepmc", "Table"];
(filtered = 
    SequenceCases[file, {{"E", ___}} | {{"P", ___, 1, 0 ..}}]) // 
  Grid[#, Alignment -> Left] &;

EsnPs = TakeList[filtered, 
   Length /@ Split[filtered[[All, 1, 1]], #2 == "P" &]];
```

Example: To get the third row, for index `i==1`,

```
EsnPs[[1, 3 + 1]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Straightforward approach:

```
d = Import["test.txt", "Table"];

extract[ps_] := Module[{pos = ps, dp, ddp, p},
                     (*List all E-lines*)                      
                  dp = Select[d, #[[1]] == "E" &];  
                     (*Define the position of desired line in global list*)         
                  p = Position[d, dp[[pos]]][[1, 1]];
                     (*Taking the first P-line going after desired E-line*)
                  ddp = Select[d[[p ;; -1]], #[[1]] == "P" &, 1]
                ]
```

Finally it gives:

```
 extract[2]
```

{"P", 7, 130, -0.0181296, 0.526965, 0.759515, 1.05, 0.49761, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}

and so on..

If you wish all P-lines going after desired E-line up to the next E-line, than you need:

```
extract[ps_] := Module[{pos = ps, dp, ddp, p1, p2},
                 dp = Select[d, #[[1]] == "E" &];
                 p1 = Position[d, dp[[pos]]][[1, 1]];
                 p2 = Position[d, dp[[pos + 1]]][[1, 1]];
                 ddp = Select[d[[p1 ;; p2]], #[[1]] == "P" &]
                ]
```

that gives:

```
 extract[2]
```

{{"P", 7, 130, -0.0181296, 0.526965, 0.759515, 1.05, 0.49761, 1, 0, 0,
0, 0}, {"P", 8, 211, 0.168652, -0.407089, -0.623444, 0.776098,
0.13957, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {"P",
9, -211, -0.150523, -0.119876, -0.136071, 0.273902, 0.13957, 1, 0,
0, 0, 0}}